# Cocos2d-x Background image sets required for iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In Cocos2d Obj.C Game, I used below code to display background.

```
CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Background.png"];
```

In folder, I put these image sets

```
Background.png              320x480
Background-hd.png       640x960
Background-ipad.png     768x1024
Background-ipadhd.png   1536x2048
```

This code is arround 3 years old. Now what are the required image sets for background in cocos2d-x ?

In Cocos2d-x,

```
auto sprite = Sprite::create("Background.png");
```

How to read background for iphone5/iphone6/iPhone7/iPadpro in cocos2d-x ? What are file extension?

what sets ideal game programmer use now?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH9Ct4R0nBM&index=4&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe

Comment: @Makalele this video tutorial created in 2014, those days iphone 6 plus wide screen not found also those days non-retina support required...now things are changed..no need to support non-hd, so which are required image sets now ? your tutorial not helps right

Comment: @Makalele Now I use 2 sets image, one for iPhone 5 size and another for ipad 2048x1536, kept same image name but read from different folder..not sure its right way...waiting for experts reply